# regexp to match each "paragraph" or "block"

Tags: regex

I'm trying to capture each "block" or "paragraph" of text from `MSH` to  `HL70126` in the following

```
MSH|^~\&amp;|12345|12345|12345|12345|20160805102500-0600||QBP^Q11^QBP_Q11|27YH-QA.1.1.2|P|2.5.1|||ER|AL|||||Z34^CDCPHINVS|^^^^^CDC^VACMANPIN^^^00001|
QPD|Z34^Request Immunization History^CDCPHINVS|37374859|F80N1908^^^AIRA^MR|LetcherAIRA^LinhAIRA^Primavera^^^^L||20180803|F|1735 Waalwijk Ln^^Kentwood^MI^49512^^P|
RCP|I|5^RD&amp;records&amp;HL70126


MSH|^~\&amp;|12345|12345|12345|12345|20160805102500-0600||QBP^Q11^QBP_Q11|27YH-QA.2.1.2|P|2.5.1|||ER|AL|||||Z44^CDCPHINVS|^^^^^CDC^VACMANPIN^^^00001|
QPD|Z44^Request Evaluated History and Forecast^CDCPHINVS|37374859|I81B1916^^^AIRA^MR|BerrienAIRA^GracelynAIRA^Aylwen^^^^L||20180803|F|1935 Ltichtse Vecht St^^Washingtn Township^MI^48095^^P|
RCP|I|5^RD&amp;records&amp;HL70126


MSH|^~\&amp;|12345|12345|12345|12345|20160805102500-0600||QBP^Q11^QBP_Q11|27YH-QA.2.1.2-D|P|2.5.1|||ER|AL|||||Z44^CDCPHINVS|^^^^^CDC^VACMANPIN^^^00001|
QPD|Z44^Request Evaluated History and Forecast^CDCPHINVS|37374859|I81B1916^^^AIRA^MR|BerrienAIRA^GracelynAIRA^Aylwen^^^^L||20180803|F|1935 Ltichtse Vecht St^^Washingtn Township^MI^48095^^P|
RCP|I|5^RD&amp;records&amp;HL70126
```

What would be the regex pattern to do so?

Comment: `MSH.*?HL70126` but with the s flag so that the dot matches newlines and the g flag so you match all of them instead of just the first: https://regex101.com/r/pakaLR/1

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to capture every single WORD text from "MHS" to "HL7016"?
To solve the aforementioned problem ;I split out three groups in regex expression.
https://regex101.com/r/pakaLR/2

(MSH)(|.+?)(HL70126)

1. (MSH) Catch "MSH" word->First Subgroup
2. (|.+?) Catch "MSH" to "HL70126"->Second Subgroup
3. (HL70126) Catch HL70126 word->Third Subgroup
4. You can use $2->Capture Group 2